# How to do LEFT JOIN with double condition in Oracle syntax?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, left-join

I have 2 tables.

1) **car** table:

[image: car table]

2) **param** table:

[image: param table]

I need to fetch duplicate cars have *owner* params match and do NOT differ in *insurance* (that's it must be either the same or is **absent for both**).

I'm successfully executing my query with `LEFT JOIN` in ANSI-syntax:

```
SELECT owner.name, owner.value, COALESCE (insur.name, 'insurance'), insur.value, count(*)
FROM car INNER JOIN param owner ON car.id = owner.car_id
LEFT JOIN param insur ON car.id = insur.car_id AND insur.name = 'insur'
WHERE owner.name = 'owner'
GROUP BY owner.name, owner.value, insur.name, insur.value
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with properly working ANSI-syntax](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0eb96/7/0)

But when I rewrote this query with `(+)` sign from Oracle syntax instead `LEFT JOIN` I have different result:

```
SELECT owner.name, owner.value, COALESCE (insur.name, 'insurance'), insur.value, count(*)
FROM car,
     param owner,
     param insur
WHERE car.id = owner.car_id
  AND owner.name = 'owner'
  AND car.id (+) = insur.car_id -- key change
  AND insur.name = 'insur'
GROUP BY owner.name, owner.value, insur.name, insur.value
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with unexpected result of (+) instead LEFT JOIN](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0eb96/11)

Result of this query is empty. I don't understand how to rewrite it in Oracle syntax to have the same result of queries.

Comment: `(+)`!!! I haven't seen that since the 90s! I think you should move to the 21st century and use `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` instead. It gives you much more flexibility.

Comment: @Michael . . . "Oracle" syntax is now `LEFT JOIN`, not `+`.

Comment: What did documentation & examples of (+) suggest? What about when you tried (+) with a given left table? Read the manual re use & limitations of (+) & its deprecation. The (+) goes on all right table columns of a left join, you're using it wrong. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Put [mcve] code in your posts as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be

```
SQL> select owner.name, owner.value,
  2    coalesce (insur.name, 'insurance') in_name,
  3    insur.value, count(*)
  4  from car, param owner, param insur
  5  where car.id = owner.car_id
  6    and car.id  = insur.car_id (+)
  7    and insur.name (+) = 'insur'
  8    and owner.name = 'owner'
  9  group by owner.name, owner.value, insur.name, insur.value
 10  having count(*) > 1;

NAME     VALUE    IN_NAME              VALUE      COUNT(*)
-------- -------- -------------------- -------- ----------
owner    John     insurance                              2

SQL>
```

Though, *why* would you want to use the *old* Oracle outer-join syntax? When compared to ANSI joins, it has only drawbacks and no advantages (at least, I can't think of any). Actually, I know one - if you use outer join in old Forms & Reports 6i (or even older? I don't think that anyone uses those versions nowadays), their *built-in* PL/SQL engine might not *speak* ANSI outer joins so you're doomed to use the old `(+)` outer join operator. Other than that ... nope, no idea.

Comment: "why would you want to use the old Oracle outer-join syntax" - you might want to check quite comprehensive comparison ansi vs old oracle style in first chapter here: https://www.apress.com/gb/book/9781484233719

Comment: For ~15 GBP, I wouldn't mind if you shared that info (in a few words), @DrYWit.

Comment: Unfortunately there are a few Oracle features that do not work (even in Oracle 12.2) with ANSI join syntax, they **require** old-style (+) Oracle notation. One of these is (join-based) materialized views with fast refresh.

Comment: Aha. Thank you, @mathguy. So how do you (not *you* personally; I mean *Oracle*) create such a view if one of those tables has to be outer joined to two (or more) tables? `(+)` allows outer joining to only one table ...

Comment: Not easily. The general idea is "by using parentheses" (which in this context means "subqueries") There are really no joins between more than two tables at a time; it may seem differently, but an Explain Plan will show how the optimizer joins two tables, then a third, etc. (and it has the flexibility to use whatever order it thinks best). To "outer join to more than one table" you have to explicitly join two tables, then join a third table to the result, etc.

Comment: I see ... lucky me, didn't have to do that. Thank you again, @mathguy.

Comment: @Littlefoot, apologies, for delay. First of all, every query with ANSI syntax eventually transformed into Oracle native syntax (except FULL JOIN and JOIN PARTITION BY). As a rule, it’s much simpler to express logic using ANSI syntax, but on the other hand, Oracle creates lateral/inline views under the hood which makes it more challenging to control the execution plan if necessary. Also hints like qb_name do not work with ANSi due to ANSI -> native conversion. These subtle differences are extremely important for complex queries, I’m not sure if it makes sense without specific examples, though.

Comment: In addition to what @mathguy already said, starting with Oracle 12 Release 1, (+) allows one table to be outer joined with two other tables. And this functionality is available for more than 4 years given that 12.1 was released in Summer 2014. Yet another point is that Oracle keeps improving native syntax even though ANSI is preferable in the most of cases.

Comment: No need for the apology, really, @DrYWit. Thank you posting that comment, much appreciated. Personally, my only objection so far (at least, the one I can remember) is that `(+)` didn't allow outer joins with more than just one table. Two of them in 12.x? Whoa, that's a 100% improvement :)