# Outer Joins with Multiple Conditions in Oracle Join Syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the tables below

```
create table xx_base_tbl
(
    tbl_id      number
,   trx_num     varchar2(100)
);


create table xx_dtl_tbl
(
    dtl_id      number
,   tbl_id      number
,   category    varchar2(100)
,   attribute1  varchar2(100)
);

insert into xx_base_tbl (tbl_id, trx_num) values (1, 'trx 1');
insert into xx_base_tbl (tbl_id, trx_num) values (2, 'trx 2');
insert into xx_base_tbl (tbl_id, trx_num) values (3, 'trx 3');
insert into xx_base_tbl (tbl_id, trx_num) values (4, 'trx 4');
insert into xx_base_tbl (tbl_id, trx_num) values (5, 'trx 5');

insert into xx_dtl_tbl (dtl_id, tbl_id, category, attribute1) values (1, 1, null, 'SAMPLE');
insert into xx_dtl_tbl (dtl_id, tbl_id, category, attribute1) values (2, 1, null, 'hello');
insert into xx_dtl_tbl (dtl_id, tbl_id, category, attribute1) values (3, 2, 'PREPAYMENT', 'this is not a value');
insert into xx_dtl_tbl (dtl_id, tbl_id, category, attribute1) values (4, 2, 'PREPAYMENT', 1);
insert into xx_dtl_tbl (dtl_id, tbl_id, category, attribute1) values (5, 3, 'PREPAYMENT', 2);
insert into xx_dtl_tbl (dtl_id, tbl_id, category, attribute1) values (6, 3, 'PREPAYMENT', 1);
insert into xx_dtl_tbl (dtl_id, tbl_id, category, attribute1) values (7, 3, 'SAMPLE', 15678);
insert into xx_dtl_tbl (dtl_id, tbl_id, category, attribute1) values (8, 4, 'PREPAYMENT', 1);
insert into xx_dtl_tbl (dtl_id, tbl_id, category, attribute1) values (9, 4, 'PREPAYMENT', NULL);
insert into xx_dtl_tbl (dtl_id, tbl_id, category, attribute1) values (10, 5, 'PREPAYMENT', null);
insert into xx_dtl_tbl (dtl_id, tbl_id, category, attribute1) values (11, 5, 'SAMPLE', 'YEY');
```

I am using the ANSI Syntax below to outer join xx_dtl_tbl to another xx_base_tbl show only CATEGORY with PREPAYMENT and numeric values only. then use `LISTAGG()` to aggregate the results into a single row

```
SELECT
    xx1.trx_num,
    LISTAGG(xx3.trx_num, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
        ORDER BY
            xx3.trx_num
    ) prepayment
FROM
         xx_base_tbl xx1
    INNER JOIN xx_dtl_tbl   xx2 ON xx1.tbl_id = xx2.tbl_id
    LEFT JOIN xx_base_tbl  xx3 ON (to_number(xx2.attribute1) = xx3.tbl_id and length(TRIM(translate(xx2.attribute1, ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) IS NULL)    
GROUP BY
    xx1.trx_num
```

The result looks fine:

```
TRX_NUM     PREPAYMENT
-------     -------------
trx 1   
trx 2       trx 1
trx 3       trx 1,trx 2
trx 4       trx 1
trx 5
```

However, when i use [SQL Developer's tool to change the syntax to Oracle Join Syntax](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcM2ksaHRDU), it get the below result:

```
SELECT
    xx1.trx_num,
    LISTAGG(xx3.trx_num, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
        ORDER BY
            xx3.trx_num
    ) prepayment
FROM
    xx_base_tbl  xx1,
    xx_dtl_tbl   xx2,
    xx_base_tbl  xx3
WHERE
        xx1.tbl_id = xx2.tbl_id
    AND to_number(xx2.attribute1) = xx3.tbl_id (+)
    AND ( length(TRIM(translate(xx2.attribute1, ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) IS NULL )
GROUP BY
    xx1.trx_num
```

The result changed:

```
TRX_NUM     PREPAYMENT
-------     -------------
trx 2       trx 1
trx 3       trx 1,trx 2
trx 4       trx 1
trx 5
```

the trx 1 row is suddenly missing. How can I write this in Oracle Syntax?

Answer (score 2):

This query is not so easy to transform to old syntax. Something which worked for me is:

```
select a.trx_num,
       listagg(b.trx_num, ',') within group (order by b.trx_num) prepayment 
  from (

    select trx_num, attribute1, 
           case when trim(translate(xx2.attribute1, ' +-.0123456789', ' ')) is null 
                then to_number(xx2.attribute1) 
           end attr_num
    from xx_base_tbl xx1, xx_dtl_tbl xx2 
    where xx1.tbl_id = xx2.tbl_id) a, 
  
    xx_base_tbl b
  
  where a.attr_num = b.tbl_id (+)
  group by a.trx_num
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5b4f9227ca5c52c3ca0154a878d92c24)

Two steps, in first create joining column using `case when` in subquery, then use it in main query.

**Edit:**

Above query may be simplified to:

```
select xx1.trx_num,  
       listagg(xx3.trx_num, ',') within group (order by xx3.trx_num) prepayment
from xx_base_tbl xx1, xx_dtl_tbl xx2, xx_base_tbl xx3
where xx1.tbl_id = xx2.tbl_id
  and case when trim(translate(xx2.attribute1, ' +-.0123456789', ' ')) is null 
            then to_number(xx2.attribute1) 
       end = xx3.tbl_id(+)
group by xx1.trx_num
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=28978c93a83b4823953221ae9cc0fee6)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that is used in your first query is ANSI standard joins and properly works with oracle.

Second query's syntax is old SQL-92 standard and should be avoided. Also, it is hard to understand and handle.

By the way, your second query will need some extra clauses as follows:

```
WHERE
    xx1.tbl_id = xx2.tbl_id
    AND to_number(xx2.attribute1) = xx3.tbl_id (+)
    AND (xx3.tbl_id is null -- this extra OR condition is needed with below condition
         or ( length(TRIM(translate(xx2.attribute1, ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) IS NULL )
        )
```

Comment: hi, yes i am aware that it works in Oracle but i need it in Oracle syntax because i am making a materialized view (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303492/how-to-do-left-join-with-double-condition-in-oracle-syntax#comment91561904_52303625)

Comment: sorry, your suggestion didn't work: `ORA-01719: outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN
01719. 00000 -  "outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN"
*Cause:    An outer join appears in an or clause.
*Action:   If A and B are predicates, to get the effect of (A(+) or B),
           try (select where (A(+) and not B)) union all (select where (B)).
Error at Line: 14 Column: 23`

Comment: See the answer, i have removee (+). Now check